# How to register windows module's win_command output in ansible task

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create an ansible task in a playbook that will run a windows batch command and register the output in a variable. Later this will be printed by ansible debug module. Here is what i have done so far.

```
---

 - name: verify port listening
   raw: netstat -na | find "8080" register=result
 - debug: msg="{{result}}"
   tags: mnc-verify
```

Then run my playbook with this

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts service.yml --tags "mnc-verify"
```

The error i get

```
fatal: [v0560a.vstage.co]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'result' is undefined"}
```

Could anyone help me please
-Raf

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing YAML syntax (`key: value`) with Ansible syntax (`key=value`).

The correct form is:

```
---
- name: verify port listening
  raw: netstat -na | find "8080"
  register: result

- debug: msg="{{result}}"
  tags: mnc-verify
```

Comment: Thanks techraf. I tries per your code initially did not work. Then tried as i shared here.